# what will be range of f(x)

Tags: functions

> Consider $f(x)=[x]+(x-\{x\})^2$ where [.] denotes floor function and $\{.\}$ fractional part of $x$.Find Range of $f$.
>
> $f$ can be re-written as $f(x)=[x]+[x]^2=[x]([x+1])$

Comment: It looks like $f(x)=[x]+[x]^2$, since $(x-\{x\})$ is simply subtracting the fractional part.

Comment: I think you mean $f(x)$ can be rewritten as $[x]+[x]^2$, right?

Comment: @Orangutango Yes, thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Recall that $\{x\} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$; it follows that

$$f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor + (x - (x - \lfloor x \rfloor))^2$$

$$f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor x \rfloor^2$$

So the range is going to be quite a bit more limited than $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

As it was said, it eqals the function $[x]+ [x]^2$, which has (imagine it as $x + x^2$) its zeros at $0$ a $-1$, for numbers between the zeroes, it always gives $0$ and elsewhere it is positive. 
You can also notice that $f(x) = f(-x-1)$, so the range are numbers of the form $n(n+1)$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$.